# stop child covering parent outline?

Tags: css, outline

Due to some elements being inside a slideshow i'm using outline with negative offset instead of border.

However the child elements are covering the outline but i want the border over them. I'm using it to frame the content.

http://jsfiddle.net/z22kw2zq/1/

```
.parent {
 position:relative; outline: green 3px solid;
  outline-offset:0px;
background-color:pink;
pading:5px;
overflow:hidden;
}
.child {position:relative; top:26px; background-color:yellow;
display:inline;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `:after` pseudo-element for outline and add `position: absolute`.

```css
.parent {
  position: relative;
  background-color: pink;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.parent:after {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  content: '';
  outline: green 3px solid;
  outline-offset: -3px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
.child {
  position: relative;
  top: 23px;
  background-color: yellow;
  display: inline;
}
p {
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">lorem ipsum doler sit amet</div>
  <p>text here</p>
</div>
```

Comment: amazing! would never of thought of using :after like that. D.

Comment: @Nenad Vracar I recently tried this and it works great except for the fact that now no event listeners work for any child content. Any workarounds?

Answer (score 2):

adding `z-index` will solve your problem:

```
.parent {
  position:relative; outline: green 3px solid;
  outline-offset: -3px;
background-color:pink;
pading:5px;
overflow:hidden;
z-index:999;
}
.child {position:relative; top:23px; background-color:yellow;
display:inline;
z-index:-1
}
```

The z-index property specifies the stack order of an element.An element with greater stack order is always in front of an element with a lower stack order.

Note: z-index only works on positioned elements (position:absolute, position:relative, or position:fixed).